# ARKitにおいて、電車に乗ってる状態でnodeの動きを電車に合わせたい

Tags: swift, swift4, arkit

SwiftとARKitを使ってアプリを作っています。
電車内にユーザーが乗った状態で、node(画像)を電車の壁に画像を貼り、 電車の動きとともにnodeが,貼られた壁とずれないようにしたいのですが、
現状電車の動きと共に動いてくれません。何かいい方法はありませんでしょうか？
壁にnodeを貼ることはできている状態です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もし、床・壁認識を使用されているのであれば、ARKit1.5から利用できる画像認識を使ってみるのはどうでしょう？
ARKitは各種センサーを使って世界を構築し、床や壁は動かないことを前提としている感じを受けるので、床・壁認識だけでは厳しいかもしれません。

画像認識では対象や端末自身が動いても追従してくれるのでうまくいくと思います。
もしダメであれば、別のARエンジンの利用を考えた方がいいかもしれませんね。